# Implement a finite state automaton in OOP

Tags: oop, software-design, automaton

I am thinking about implementing a program with finite state automaton in an OOP language like Java or C++.

What would you think is the best way to implement this with a manageable amount of available states, regarding to good software design?

Is it good to implement for each state an own class?
If yes, how to do the bridge between two states?

Thanks for any comment!

Comment: You might wanna look at: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_43_0/libs/statechart/doc/index.html

Comment: How state automata are implemented in analysis tools, some OO systems using virtual dispatch, or production quality systems using static dispatch and code generation differs greatly. You are unlikely to get something which allows the tracing and logging you want to debug a state machine in a simulator and which will run a protocol at gigabit speeds - the best way of implementing the machine varies based on what you want it to be capable of doing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this just to flex your programming muscle, or for an actual project etc? In either case it depends on what you want the state machine for:
- is it to manage tasks in some sort of workflow
- is it to determine application flow state
- is it for a business rules engine etc

In the case of a project, I would suggest that, depending on what your target use is, you look for libraries in that domain. Java for example has MANY MANY libraries for workflow/busines flows, as well as tons of rules engines (Drools comes to mind right of the bat, although it is a complex behemoth)

Comment: At the moment is is more a quastion of interest...during my study we had automatons in theory (very thoroughly), at this time I didn't understand, what they could be good for. Now I'm thinking about writing a (not very big) web project, using those

Answer (score 0):

Try this - the section on design is good and it shows a use for a fsm
http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/wa-finitemach1/

Another use I've seen is to implement managed objects for a computer service, with the transition "start" moving the object from the "down" to the "starting" state etc using an extennsion of the OMG managed object life-cycle

Answer (score 0):

The [dk.brics.automaton](http://www.brics.dk/automaton/) library is good implementation of FSA's in Java. It's build with performance in mind, so it trades in some OOP principles for speed, but i'd recommend you take a look at it.